# PHP - make $_FILES filenames safe

Tags: php, arrays, function, json

I have an form that contains an "attachments" field, allowing a user to add multiple attachments. Each attachment is then uploaded but before doing so, each file name is made safe using the following function.

```
function safeFile($file) {  

    $lower = strtolower($file);
    $trim = rtrim($lower, '.');
    $regex = array('#[^A-Za-z0-9\.\_\- ]#');

    return trim(preg_replace($regex, '', $trim));       
}
```

So far so good.

I'm then json encoding the file names to store in the database. using the following:

```
json_decode($_FILES['attachment']['name']);
```

This outputs the following in the database:

```
["FILE.jpg", "OTHER.jpg"]
```

This works, however I'm also trying to call the `safeFile()` function so that the same action is applied before inserting into the database as it does when uploaded.

I tried using the following which did not work.

```
json_encode( safeFile($_FILES['add_attachment']['name']) );
```

To get around this, thinking logically, would I have to create a `foreach` loop, then making each individual file name safe, then return an array?

Could someone please shove me in the right direction?

Comment: Try [`array_map`](http://php.net/array-map)`("safeFile",$_FILES['add_attachment']['name']);`

Comment: Whilst array_map is nice, the foreach proposed in the question would work fine, so im wondering why you didnt try that before asking the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a foreach loop

You need to use [array_map()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) like this

```
array_map("safeFile", $_FILES['add_attachment']['name']);
```

Also, what I think you need to be using is [json_encode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) not json_decode

Comment: Thank you. Worked a charm :) I was using json_encode, but I made a mistake when typing it.